# Entity Framework: Automatically sorting generic DbSet by primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

As part of a generic repository pattern I have a `DbSet<TEntity>` - a generic Entity Framework `IQueryable` collection. The type of `TEntity` could vary, but I know I want to sort by whatever the primary key is.

Can I do this generically in EF, without knowing the type in advance? Otherwise how can we do Skip() -> Take() for repeaters without knowing the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These [extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550930/apply-orderby-with-dbset) assumes that a key field in your entity class is properly decorated with the Key attribute.

Comment: Using the `[Key]` attribute is only one way to indicate the primary-key property. The most reliable way is to query the context metadata to determine the primary-key.

Comment: Good answer. I think I'm going to make my own [DefaultSort] attribute and use your extension method to find it (or throw an exception if it isn't there).